# Only get unique values as json response from database

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs, database, visual-studio-code

I have a database and understand in sql I can get unique values via:
`Select DISTINCT name, industry from database;`
however when I access it via local host and look at the json response i get duplicate values from different times.

code in VSCODE:

```
  req.db.from('database').select("name","symbol")
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json({ "Error": false, "Message": "Success", "Database": rows })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({ "Error": true, "Message": "Error in MYSQL query" })
    })
});
```

what do I need to alter to only receive the name and symbol of each response once and not for every single entry of that object in the database?

Comment: I do NOT see something in your code which will perform DISTINCT. Either add distincting construction (maybe `.selectdistinct`, maybe `.select().distinct` - look for correct syntax if exists) or grouping construction (`SELECT name, industry FROM database GROUP BY  name, industry;`)

Answer (score 0):

ah simply .distinct. didn't work earlier for some reason but is working now. rookie :')